# $\|A\begin{bmatrix} m\\n \end{bmatrix}\| = \|B\begin{bmatrix} m\\n \end{bmatrix}\| $, what can be said about A and B?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given two 2x2 matrices A and B such that for some real m and n: $$\|A\begin{bmatrix}
m\\n
\end{bmatrix}\| = \|B\begin{bmatrix}
m\\n
\end{bmatrix}\| $$

The norm is euclidean, and $A\ne B$ and $m\ne 0$ and $n \ne 0$. Can anything interesting be said about the relationship between A and B? ie: some relationship between the trace, or determinants etc... Thanks.

Comment: Their ranks differ by at most 1. Otherwise nothing interesting to say...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing interesting can be said, and almost anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Vert Ax \Vert=\Vert Bx \Vert$ for every $x$, then in particular:

$\sup \Vert Ax \Vert = \sup \Vert Bx \Vert$ for $\Vert x \Vert=1$.

Then by the definition of the induced norm, $\Vert A \Vert_2 = \Vert B \Vert_2$ (the largest singular value of $A$ is equal to the largest singular value of $B$).